# JavaFX CSS Parser error Expected COLON

Tags: java, css, javafx

so I got an error and I don't know what to fix cuz from my point of view there's everything allright:

CSS Code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Titillium';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('Titillium.ttf');
}

.root{
    -fx-font-family: "Titillium";
}

.label{
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
}

.title {
    -fx-font-size: 24pt;
}

.textfield{
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
}

.list-cell{
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
}

.combo-box{
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
}

#detaillist .list-cell{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

#subtitle{
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
}
```

and the Java Code where I set the Sytle:

```
title = new Label("Notiz vom " + Selector.getSelectedNotiz().getDatum().toLocaleString());
title.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
//--------------- Right here ----------------------
title.setStyle("title");
cmbLernender = new ComboBox<String>();
k = new Label("Kompetenz");
k.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
```

this looks fine...

now if I start it this happens:

```
Sep 15, 2014 1:25:30 PM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNUNG: CSS Error parsing '*{title}: Expected COLON at [1,7]
```

thanks for the help.

Peace

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to set a `styleclass` to `Label` *title*. When you want to set `styleclass` use :

```
title.getStyleClass().add("title");
```

If you want to add styles directly to your control, instead of loading them from a css/styleclass, you can use :

```
title.setStyle("-fx-background-color: slateblue; -fx-text-fill: white;");
```

Comment: Isn't the real problem the useage of "@font-face" which is not supported in javafx?

Comment: `@font-face` has no effect whatsoever. The problem is the way styleclass is being added to the `Label`

Comment: @tomsontom is right, the error is a css parse error. it was supported from javafx8:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intropublicapi